# Python round() to remove trailing zeros

Tags: python, math

The code below is used to find the `x*` using **Gradient Descent** and the problem here is that the final result of `req8` is `-1.00053169969469` and when I round it, it results in `-1.00000000000000`.

How can I round to get `-1.0` or `-1.00` instead, **without** using any other module?

```
from sympy import * 
import numpy as np 

global x, y, z, t 
x, y, z, t = symbols("x, y, z, t") 

def req8(f, eta, xi, tol): 
    dx = diff(f(x), x)
    arrs = [xi]
    for i in range(100):
        x_star = arrs[-1] - eta * round(dx.subs(x, arrs[-1]), 7)
        if abs(dx.subs(x, x_star)) < tol:
            break
        arrs.append(x_star)
    print(arrs[-1])
    print(round(arrs[-1], 2))

def f_22(x):
    return x**2 + 2*x - 1
req8(f_22, 0.1, -5, 1e-3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `format` function to print your rounded result with the desired number of digits (2, in the example below):

```py
print("{:.2f}".format(round(arrs[-1], 2)))
```

**EDIT:** as pointed out by @SultanOrazbayev, rounding is no longer necessary here and you may print your result using the following expression:

`print("{:.2f}".format(arrs[-1]))`

Comment: Wouldn't `print("{:.2f}".format(arrs[-1]))` be sufficient? (just checking)

Comment: Good point! It looks like `format` is taking care of the rounding.

Comment: `print("{:.2f}".format(round(1.9999, 2)))` and `print("{:.2f}".format(1.9999))` both return `2.00`.